# Computing $\lim_{x\to-5}\frac{x^2+2x-15}{|x+5|}$

Tags: calculus

The problem is: $$\lim_{x\to-5}\frac{x^2+2x-15}{|x+5|}$$

I factored the numerator to get: $\frac{(x-3)(x+5)}{|x+5|}$

How do i solve the rest?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What is $\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}(x+5)/|x+5|$?

Comment: sorry the limit is x->-5

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

- if $x \rightarrow -5^+$ then $x+5 > 0$
- if $x \rightarrow -5^-$ then $ x+5 < 0$

You'll find that the limit doesn't exist because $\lim_{x\rightarrow -5^+} f(x) \neq \lim_{x\rightarrow -5^-} f(x)$.

Comment: i cancelled out the two (x+5) out and my answer is now -2. Am i going in the right direction?

Comment: How did you obtain $-2$?

Comment: if you cancelled out the $x+5$ you should have $\lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} -x+3$

Comment: i did -5 +3 and got -2

Comment: Why did you substitute $-5$?Does the limit tend to $-\infty$?

Comment: so im not supposed to substitute the -5? and when i cancelled (x+5)/-(x+5) only x-3 remains

Comment: I don't get where you took the $-5$, you should 'substitute' $-\infty$

Comment: the limit is x to -5

Comment: so it is -2 correct?

Comment: why doesnt it exist

Comment: see the new update

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{(x-3)(x+5)}{ |x+5|} = (x-3)\frac{(x+5)}{ |x+5|}=(x-3)\text{sign}(x+5)$$
As $x \to -\infty$, then $\text{sign}(x+5)=-1$, So $(x-3)\text{sign}(x+5)=-x+3 \to \infty$.

**Addition.**
If we take limit point $x=-5$, then of course we come from infinite limit to non existence of limit. First multiplier $x-3 \to -8, x \to -5$, but second as $\text{sign}(x+5)$ have different one-sided limits $\pm 1.$ So $\mp 8$ for product.

Comment: I think there's a typo: $-x+3\rightarrow \infty$ as $x\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: @Äres. Thanks for remark, of course you are right. But question changed, limit point now is "$-5$", so I make addition accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Another place where "factor out the big part" helps.  Here, $|x|$ is growing without bound so $x^2$ is the big part in the numerator and $|x|$ is the big part in the denominator.
\begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{x^2 + 2x - 15}{|x+5|}   \\
&= \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{x^2(1 + 2/x - 15/x^2)}{|x(1+5/x)|}   \\
    &= \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{x^2}{|x|} \frac{1 + 2/x - 15/x^2}{|1+5/x|}
\end{align*}
We should be able to see that the second fraction is going to $\frac{1+0-0}{|1+0|}$.  (Making this easy to see is *why* you factor out the "big part".)  The first fraction is always positive (positive over positive) once $x < 0$, so
$$ L = \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} (|x| \cdot 1) = \infty  \text{.}  $$

Answer (score 1):

After the correction in the limit $x\rightarrow -5$.

Recall that $|x+5|=\begin{cases}x+5 \space\space \text{if $x\geq-5$} \\-(x+5)\space\space \text{if $x<-5$}\end{cases}.$ Then

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow (-5)^{-}}\frac{(x-3)(x+5)}{|x+5|}=\lim_{x\rightarrow (-5)^{-}}\frac{(x-3)(x+5)}{-(x+5)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow (-5)^{-}}-(x-3)=-(-5-3)=8$ since we approach from $x<-5$
- $\lim_{x\rightarrow (-5)^{+}}\frac{(x-3)(x+5)}{|x+5|}=\lim_{x\rightarrow (-5)^{+}}\frac{(x-3)(x+5)}{(x+5)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow (-5)^{+}}(x-3)=-5-3=-8$ since we approach from $x>-5.$

Thus the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You even don't have to factor whatever if you use asymptotic equivalents:
a polynomial is equivalent to its leading term, and $|x+5|\sim_{-\infty} |x|$, so
$$\frac{x^2+2x-15 }{|x+5|}\sim_{-\infty} \frac{x^2}{|x|}=\frac{|x|^2}{|x|}=|x|.$$